# WPF allign button one beside other

Tags: c#, wpf, alignment

Im trying to align 3 buttons one beside one in the center of a grid.

This is what i tried so far:

```
   <Grid>

    <StackPanel >
    <Button>button1</Button>
    <Button>button1</Button>
    <Button>button1</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

i tried to use a stackpanel but it stack them one on each other ..but i want one beside one..
How can it be done?
Thanks in advance! i'll appreciate any help.
Answer:

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
           </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This,

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
    <Button Width="100" Height="30">button1</Button>
    <Button Width="100" Height="30">button1</Button>
    <Button Width="100" Height="30">button1</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: thanks but i want them to look normal.. not streched till the end .. :) @Abin Mathew

Comment: @itapi normal means ?

Comment: @itapi Glad you find it. but can you explain about what you find ?

Comment: @  Abin Mathew look post

Answer (score 0):

Just use another grid inside the main grid

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="0">button1</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="1">button1</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="2">button1</Button>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct answer:

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
       </StackPanel>
```